# capistrano install not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, capistrano, ubuntu-18.04

I have recently updated my OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.
But now I have an issue with capistrano and ruby. 
Indeed, I would like to deploy a php app with capistrano. 
So I installed ruby with rbenv, bundler with gem and when I run "bundle install" everything is well installed. 
My issue is when I run "cap install" to use capistrano and create all the files in my app. 
I have the following message : 
`/usr/bin/env: «ruby2.3»: No such file or directory`

Do you know how to solve it and use capistrano ?

More informations :

- ruby version : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]
- I have followed the following instructions to install ruby : https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04
- I have zsh so I replaced .bashrc by .zshrc

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Did you install ruby ? and have you set the path, can you also run `which ruby` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, he has ruby because he says Ruby version and the guide installs Ruby.

Comment: Could you run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` inside of the project folder on the server. I had same problem, and the problem occurred because on my container I didn't ignore `vendor` folder. I know this is not container, but could you try it?

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir The reason, I asked for if he installed ruby was, if he did it, rbenv path should be set by defualt in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`. From the error `/usr/bin/env` it means the path is not set.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I can run ruby, I found ruby in rbenv folder when I ran  `which ruby` and I have the ruby version when I did `ruby -v` 
So I think ruby it's well installed and in the path. I have containers too and I have tested `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`. The bundled gems are well installed in vendor/bundle but when I run `cap install` I have still the `no such file or directory` error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that I had this message is because I ran `cap install` directly on the console and not `bundle exec cap install`... 
So now it's working.